# Why does Joomla add xml tag if article contains word "XHTML"?

Tags: xml, joomla

I have a problem with Joomla. When text of article contains word **XHTML** (uppercase) Joomla adds tag

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

above html tag

it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-gb" dir="ltr">
<head>
......

<p>... Systems Team XHTML</p>
```

if I use low case **xhtml** in the text it works correctly

What is wrong?

Comment: What editor are you using? Try changing the editor to none.  Also one solution might be to wrap the lower case in a span and use `text-transform: uppercase` .

Comment: @ВикторГоловко If you are not receiving the desired support here, you might try posting at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.